# vim script "input()" function that doesn't require user to hit enter

Tags: vim

I would like to have the user call my function and then have the function request user input but I do not want the user to have to type 'enter' after typing a letter as is required by the "input()" function. For instance, the user should be able to type single letter commands like 'h','j','k','l' and each letter typed would loop around my function until the user typed 'x' for exit. If I use "input()" then the user would have to type 'h`<enter>`','j`<enter>`'...

Any suggestions on how I might be able to do this?

If more clarification is needed please let me know.

**UPDATE**

Got it working:

```
function! s:getchar()
  let c = getchar()
  if c =~ '^\d\+$'
    let c = nr2char(c)
  endif
  return c
endfunction

" Interactively change the window size
function! InteractiveWindow()
  let char = "s"
  while char =~ '^\w$'
    echo "(InteractiveWindow) TYPE: h,j,k,l to resize or a for auto resize"
    let char = s:getchar()
    if char == "h" | call SetWindowSize( "incr" ,-5 ,0 ) | endif
    if char == "j" | call SetWindowSize( "incr"  ,0 ,5 ) | endif
    if char == "k" | call SetWindowSize( "incr"  ,0 ,-5) | endif
    if char == "l" | call SetWindowSize( "incr"  ,5 ,0 ) | endif
    if char == "a" | call SetWindowSize( "abs"  ,0  ,0 ) | endif
    redraw
  endwhile
endfunction
```

Comment: I really like the functionality this bit of code provides. It essentially lets you create a new vim mode, for instance you could call the code above a "window-mode" just like visual-mode or insert-mode. Pretty powerful stuff...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

getchar()

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#getchar()

Comment: @stephen (and anyone else) -- I'm curious how you're presenting the prompt to the user for input that can be captured with getchar().  Maybe I'm dense but it's not jumping out at me.

Comment: I actually haven't implemented it yet (and why I did not mark it as correct yet) but from looking around it seems like getchar will work for me. I am hoping to get a change to implement it later tonight, so I will let you know.