# Highlight f key searches in vim

Tags: vim

Often when I'm using `f` to search for characters in the current line, I'll run into more occurrences of the character than I expected so highlighting each search match would be nice.

In the example below, let's say I'm starting at the beginning of the line and am trying to get to `e` in vowels. It would be helpful to highlight each of those occurrences so that I could get some context on the number of times to press `;` after the initial search

```
# Here is a comment with a lot of vowels and I have passed it now
```

**How does Vim's current implementation of `f` know how to wait for only a single character instead of a newline?**

I would prefer to overwrite the builtin `f` functionality so I'm using a remap similar to this, but **one** of the problems is that it expects me to press enter at the end.

```
nnoremap f :call HighlightFSearches(input(''))<CR>
```

Currently have some issues with implementing my function `HighlightFSearches` as well, but one problem at a time.

Also, not really looking for a plugin and yes I know I can just do a search instead of using `f` but my brain seems to prefer going with `f` first in a lot of cases.

---

**Update**

Here's my final solution with much thanks to @filbranden below!

```
function! HighlightFSearches(cmd)
  " Get extra character for the command.
  let char = nr2char(getchar())

  if char ==# ''
    " Skip special keys: arrows, backspace...
    return ''
  endif

  " Highlight 'char' on the current line.
  let match_str = 'match Visual "\%' . line('.') . 'l' . char . '"'
  execute match_str

  " Finally, execute the original command with char appended to it
  return a:cmd.char
endfunction
```

```
" highlight searches using 'f'
nnoremap <expr> f highlighting#HighlightFSearches('f')
nnoremap f<bs> <nop>
vnoremap <expr> f highlighting#HighlightFSearches('f')
vnoremap f<bs> <nop>

" highlight searches using 'F'
nnoremap <expr> F highlighting#HighlightFSearches('F')
nnoremap F<bs> <nop>
vnoremap <expr> F highlighting#HighlightFSearches('F')
vnoremap F<bs> <nop>
```

Note that I chose the Highlight Group used for visual selects. You could choose a different one or make your own too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vim script "input()" function that doesn't require user to hit enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189239/vim-script-input-function-that-doesnt-require-user-to-hit-enter)

Comment: Try some of existing plugins. Maybe, [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion)?

Comment: @jeremysprofile not a dupe, but a good answer will make use of info there.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you should use [`getchar()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getchar%28%29) to get a single character from the user.

The long answer is that this gets somewhat complicated pretty quickly, since you need to deal with special keys and corner cases while handling `getchar()`.

Note that `getchar()` may return a number (for a normal keypress, which you can convert to a character with [`nr2char()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#nr2char%28%29)), or a string, starting with a special 0x80 byte for special keys (backspace, arrows, etc.)

A simplistic approach (but somewhat effective) is that running `nr2char()` on the strings returned for the special keys will return an empty string, so we can use that to skip those.

The next advice is that you can use [`<expr>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cexpr%3E) in your mappings to return the new command as a string. That, together with non-recursive mappings, allow you to return the actual `f` command itself at the end of the function, so that part of emulating it is taken care of!

Finally, one more trick you might want to use is to create a "dummy" mapping for `f` followed by an invalid character. The fact that such a 2-character mapping exists makes it so that your `f` mapping won't trigger until a second character has been entered, and this will prevent Vim from moving the cursor to the last line while waiting for a character, making the `f` emulation more seamless.

Putting it all together:

```
function! HighlightFSearches(cmd)
  " Get extra character for the command.
  let char = nr2char(getchar())

  if char ==# ''
    " Skip special keys: arrows, backspace...
    return ''
  endif

  " Here you'll want to highlight "char"
  " on the current line.

  " Finally, execute the original command.
  return a:cmd.char
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> f HighlightFSearches('f')
nnoremap f<bs> <nop>
```

The function is written in a way that you can easily reuse it for `F`, `t` and `T`.

---

For highlighting the matches, you can either use [`:match`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#match-highlight) (or `:2match`, `:3match`) or maybe you could set `@/` and let `'hlsearch'` do the highlighting...

You'll probably want to anchor the regexp on the current line, so only those matches are highlighted, see [`:help /\%l`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25l) for what you can use for that.

Finally, you'll probably want to clear the highlighting if you move to a different line. Take a look at the [CursorMoved](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#CursorMoved) event of `autocmd` for that purpose.

There are quite a few details to iron out, but hopefully this will clarify how to emulate the command part of getting the character to search for.

Comment: Thanks so much @filbranden! I didn't know about `<expr>` or `getchar()` and several other things you linked in your answer above!

Comment: Wasn't sure how to use `CursorMoved` since the docs mention that it gets triggered very often and I didn't want it to slow things down but a great idea honestly

Comment: @J-Win Feel free to ask a separate question about CursorMoved, you'll want to register while you're on the line and unregister it as soon as you leave that line. Happy to go into details on a question about it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on Vi/Vim Stack Exchange! I've posted a question over there if you'd still like to help: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21008/register-cursormoved-on-certain-key-press-and-disable-when-move-to-new-line

Comment: @J-Win I just answered that one. You're now deep in the path of quickly becoming a Vim plug-in author! 

Answer (score 2):

The short and sweet answer is to substitute `input()` for `getchar()`